# Greasemonkey: using XPath to get elements from distant XML-document

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, greasemonkey

What Im trying to do with my Greasemonkey script is:

- to read some distant XML document;
- convert it into XML object;
- and then use XPath to get the elements inside of it.

The *getElementsByTagName(TagName)* method works fine with my XML-object, but *evaluate("XPath expression")* doesn't. Any suggestions? See the code below:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
   method: "GET",
   url: "http://www.someserver.com/atom.xml",
   onload: function(response) {
      if (!response.responseXML) { 
         var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response.responseText, "application/xml"); 
      }

// this section works fine and returns the data of the first <entry>..</entry> 
      var snapEntries = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("entry");
          alert (snapEntries[0].data);

// this section doesn't work for unknown reason and returns nothing         
      var snapEntriesXpath = xmlDoc.evaluate("//entry", xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
          alert (snapEntriesXpath.snapshotItem(0).data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, the `.data` attribute won't be present for every kind of search.

You ***probably*** need to use:

```js
var snapEntriesXpath = xmlDoc.evaluate (
    "//entry//text()", xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null
);
```

---

But several other issues could be at play.  If that doesn't do it, (1) link to the exact XML file; use [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) if necessary. (2) Report what Firefox's error console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) reports.

Comment: no. it doens't seem to be a reason for non-wrking XPath evaluation. I could add alert(snapEntries.length) and alert (snapEntriesXpath.snapshotLength) in my code above. in the first case it retruns the number of entries, in the secodn it returns 0.

Comment: Well, then, the XML document is not what you think, or you edited the `evaluate` statement.  The code works on a suitable XML document, I just retested it to make sure.  Remember that XPath is case-sensitive. Provide the information requested.

Comment: OK. there must be something wrong with XML-document (however it's a standard blogger feed atom). well, it's been much faster for me to parse its *response.responseText* by using regular expressions :)